# VS C++ project built locally but not on TFS build, even though binded

Tags: visual-studio, tfs, tfvc

I have a solution with 2 projects: `MyC#Proj`, `MYCppProj`.

Right click on solution->properties->Configuration: The two projects appear under all configurations and platforms. In `Any CPU`: `MyC#Proj` platform = `Any CPU`, `MyCppProj` platform = `x64`.

Click on Configuration Manager: e.g. Configuration `Debug`, platform `Any CPU`: `MyC#Proj` platform is `Any CPU`, `MyCppProj` platform is `x64`. Both are marked Build true.

Under "Change Source Control", both projects are binded, binding path looks good, connected, status valid.

Building solution on dev machine from clean folder, both projects are built successfully.

Building in TFS build, it seems `MyCppProj` isn't built: Looking in the Log File there is no mention of the project and also the expected `x64` folder on the build server isn't created. `MyC#Proj` is built in `Any CPU`.

Comment: 1. Would you please share the yaml file you used to build your solution in TFS? 2. Please share the project files of `MyC#Proj` and `MYCppProj`. 3. Please share your solution file. 4. What's the version of your TFS? Then I can test further from my side.